# Android Html.fromHtml in TextView - align image with text

Tags: android

I'm using Html.fromHtml to populate a textview. I want to align text right next to the img but the text seems to aligning with the bottom of the image. In html, you could assign an align attribute to the img tag and the text would align to the top of the image. But the align just seems to be ignored. Is there any way this can be achieved using the textview. 
I cannot use a webview.

Comment: I don't think so, Html in android only implements a really small part of HTML.

Answer (score 3):

While probably it can't be solved with Html.fromHtml, you can have a LinearLayout and inside that an ImageView and a TextView, and then you can set alignments the way you want!